# Creating an Array of Objects - Inheriting from a Class Template and using Constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, constructor

So here's my template class declaration:

```
template <class elemType>
class listType
```

I have a constructor like this:

```
listType(const elemType &, const elemType &, const elemType &, 
const elemType &, const elemType &){

list[0] = a;
list[1] = b;
list[2] = c;
list[3] = d;
list[4] = e;

}
```

With a protected member variable like this:

```
elemType *list;
```

This is to pass in objects of type stockType in my code. I inherited a class from this template class listType called stockListType and tried to make a constructor that would pass in the parameters to the already made constructor in listType with this:

```
stockListType :: stockListType(const stockType &a, const 
stockType &b, const stockType &c, const stockType &d, const 
stockType &e) : listType(a, b, c, d, e) {

}
```

I'm not sure if I understand how to use class templates and constructors with class templates that I inherited a class from.

I tried making 5 objects of type stockType (inputting their information for their member variables using a file) and then trying to use the constructor of the inherited class with those objects in my main code:

```
stockListType object(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5);
```

But I keep getting an error when it tries to run.

EDIT:
The error I get is  Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

The child class header is:

```
#ifndef stockListTypeHeader_h
#define stockListTypeHeader_h

#include "listType Header.h"

class stockListType : public listType <class stockType>
{
public:
stockListType(const stockType &, const stockType &, const stockType &, const 
stockType &, const stockType &);

void sortList();
void swap(stockType&, stockType&);

const void printList();

protected:
    stockType *sortIndicesGainLoss;




};


#endif /* stockListTypeHeader_h */
```

And the .cpp file of the child class is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stockListTypeHeader.h"
#include "stockType.h"
#include <iostream>


void stockListType:: sortList(){
    sortIndicesGainLoss = list;

for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j =0; j<5-i-1; j++) {
        if (sortIndicesGainLoss[j].getStockSymbol() > 
sortIndicesGainLoss[j+1].getStockSymbol()){
            swap(sortIndicesGainLoss[j], sortIndicesGainLoss[j+1] );
        }
        }
    }
}

void stockListType:: swap(stockType &xp, stockType &yp){
stockType temp = xp;
xp = yp;
yp = temp;

}

 void const stockListType:: printList() {
     for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
         cout << sortIndicesGainLoss[i];

}

 stockListType :: stockListType(const stockType &a, const stockType &b, const 
stockType &c, const stockType &d, const stockType &e) : listType(a, b, c, d, e) 
{

}
```

EDIT 3:

Thank you all for helping me, I figured out it was because I hadn't initialized list or my sortIndicesGainLoss.

Now I am getting an error under my sortList method. Does anybody have a clue as to why?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Lastly please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "*But I keep getting an error when it tries to run.*" What error? Please [edit] the question to copy and paste full error message into it.

Comment: show us the structure of the child class...

Comment: The error I get is : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) @Yksisarvinen

Comment: @marvinIsSacul I added the header and .cpp file of the child class in my edit.

Comment: Where are you allocating memory for the `list` array? Or for `sortIndicesGainLoss` for that matter

Comment: Where I use the "new" keyword? I haven't used the new keyword at all. Maybe that's the reason why. I just don't know how to assign those new dynamic objects to pre-existing objects?

Comment: I thought you could create a pointer and just assign its indexes to objects as you pleased, I didn't know you had to use "new?" Is that what you mean by allocating memory for it?

Comment: You have uninitialized pointers, they don't point to valid memory - dereferencing them like you do invokes *undefined behavior*. That has nothing to do with templates or inheritance. Also you should prefer `std::vector` over pointers for this

Comment: *"I thought you could create a pointer and just assign its indexes to objects as you pleased"* - Where did you learn that? It's completely wrong and any decent course or textbook should be explaining it

Comment: We have not learned about vectors yet in school, maybe I should take up and learn that. I'm still very new to programming, but I guess I should be practicing more.

Comment: I thought I initialize list in my constructor? In my listType constructor, that is

Comment: Thank you, that's the reason I keep getting errors.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error around the point where I do: sortIndicesGainLoss = list;  The error says: Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Answer (score 2):

`elemType *list;` is **not** initialized. I really think that's the problem right there. try initializing it in the constructor to something like

`list = new elemType [5];` since you'll be using 5 elements.

```
listType(const elemType &, const elemType &, const elemType &, 
const elemType &, const elemType &){

    this->list = new elemType [5];

    list[0] = a;
    list[1] = b;
    list[2] = c;
    list[3] = d;
    list[4] = e;

}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error around the point where I do: sortIndicesGainLoss = list;

Comment: try not using `sortIndicesGainLoss`.  try removing `sortIndicesGainLoss = list;` and use `list` directly.

Comment: so replace every instance of `sortIndicesGainLoss` with `list`

Comment: @JeJo perhaps Alexandra wants to learn about pointers, and manual memory management  before going on to use already implemented libraries. We should not judge people on their methodology of programming.

Comment: I appreciate the help @JeJo. In all honesty, that article you linked to confuses me (Rule of three/five.) o.O. I will learn how to use vectors when I have the time, as a busy college student and with other things such as bible studies, I barely have enough time!  Thank you marvinIsSacul also for all your help. I am now having a problem with my sortList() method for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, in the constructor of `listType` you are not allocating memory for the array `list`. If your class has a member of type `* elemType`, this would be a pointer to a `elemType`, but it does not mean it points to allocated memory.
A solution to your problem is to write the constructor of `listType` as follows:

```
listType(const elemType &, const elemType &, const elemType &, 
const elemType &, const elemType &) : list(new elemType[5]) {

list[0] = a;
list[1] = b;
list[2] = c;
list[3] = d;
list[4] = e;

}
```

But then do not forget to deallocate `list` when your object gets destructed. You need a distructor inside the definition of the class `list` as:

```
virtual ~listType { delete[] list; }
```

The destructor should be virtual, see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

That said, rather than using C-style arrays, if the size of the array `list` is known at compile time, I would rather suggest to use the C++11 arrays. So, in the declaration of the class `listType` your protected member `list` should be declared as

```
std::array<elemType, 5> list;
```

Then you do not need anymore to allocate and deallocate "manually" the array `list`. Also, you need to `#include <array>`

As for the second error when `sortIndicesGainLoss = list;`: you do not need the member `stockType *sortIndicesGainLoss`. In fact, by calling the constructor of the base class `listType`, you have already initialized the array `list` of `elemType`, which, being protected, is accessible to `stockListType`. So to solve the problem:

- Remove `stockType *sortIndicesGainLoss` from the declaration of `stockListType`
- In the cpp file remove `sortIndicesGainLoss = list;`, and everywhere use the inherited member `list` instead of `sortIndicesGainLoss`

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helps. So when I use a C++11 array, I do not need to use delete [] anymore? I will have to use that from now on.

Comment: Also, now I am getting an error under my sortList() method. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @Alexandra: If you declare ```list``` as a C++11 you do not need to use ```delete[]```. You should think it like a normal variable, which gets automatically deleted when it exits the scope. For the error in ```sortList()``` please check first my updated answer.

Comment: @francesco I seriousy don't understand why you and others are throwing the kid with the std library. Because I think the kid wants to learn the language first (hence he creates his own algorithms), not the libraries. He'll get to learn them as time goes on.

Comment: @marvinIsSacul I think I have proposed *both* to "manually" use arrays and a self-defined swap, or to use the std library....

Comment: Alright, it's alright everyone, both are helpful jeesh lol. And changing the swap to listType variables and changing temp as a variable of listType caused an error. 0.0

Comment: I have another class called stockType which I didn't post here.... maybe that's confusing you?

Comment: @Alexandra what error do you get now? can you post the modified swap you are trying to use?

Comment: Since in my for loop list[j] and list[j+1] are referring to stockType objects since my list array is a pointer to an array of stockType objects it gives me an error: Non-const lvalue reference to type 'listType<stockType>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'stockType'

Comment: Where the for loop starts at for(int i =0; i<5; i++) it gives me a green error message saying Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Comment: @Alexandra: sorry, your ```swap``` should be actually OK.

Comment: Thank you @francesco! I found out my problem. I accidentally put in a breakpoint in my xcode OTL. It was causing my code to stop at that point and I thought it was an error message. Lol. Thank you.